# How can I "quickly" scan and digitize many negatives?

Tags: automation, negative-scanner, negative-film

I've found a huge collection of old family photos that are the negative strips (roughly 6 pictures a strip). I had a scanner that would allow me to digitally save the photos from the negatives one at a time; however, this seems like it will take me a century to do them all.  What's my options in either hardware or taking them somewhere to get done that will go faster than my current method?  [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ICOB78K) is a similar scanner to the one I'm using now.